# unable to get ['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']] in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

[image]

I trying to get the value "Automobiles : 3"

```
  tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(tooltipItem));
          return data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        },
      }
}
```

But its returns "Tourism and hospital" only. How to get "Automobiles : 3" value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log(data);` is your friend here

Comment: data===============>[object Object]
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: I can't see that data...

Comment: *core.es5.js* - Are you using Angular?

Comment: Yes @Derek 朕會功夫.. Angular 4

Comment: in that case, what about `.getDatasetMeta()` ? Circular structure needs to be processed before logging, you can find how to do it here too